# Why are these properties not enumerable?

Tags: javascript, object, enumerable

I have a simple object of objects:

```
window.abilities = {
            migrate:{
                name:"Migrate",
                description:"Move your tribe to another area; generate all new resources. Takes one time unit.",
                image:"migrate.png",
                action:"Migrate",
                unlocked:true
            },
            eradicate:{
                name:"Eradicate species",
                description:"Remove a troublesome plant or animal",
                image:"migrate.png",
                action:"Eradicate",
                unlocked:false
            }
        }
```

I am using a for ... in ... loop to iterate over this object and generate UI elements:

```
for(ability in window.abilities){
    if(ability.unlocked){
        $("#abilities").append(genAbilityCard(ability.name,ability.image,ability.description,ability.action));
    }
}
```

However, each ability variable is empty - it only has the key and not the properties (name, description, and so forth). These properties seem to be unenumerable - even though properties created this way should be enumerable by default!

How can I make these properties enumerable implicitly, without using Object.defineProperty or something unwieldy like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object). This is an old and well answered question, the loop only gets you the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating by using `for..of` and `Object.values` (ES6 only):

```
for (const ability of Object.values(window.abilities)){
    if (ability.unlocked){
        $("#abilities").append(genAbilityCard(ability.name,ability.image,ability.description,ability.action));
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! I couldn't get anything in the allegedly existing answer to work, but this solved it.

Comment: Glad to help! The only caveat about that solution is that it is limited to >= ES6. If you need to work on < ES5 (no babel available, old browser, etc.), take a look at @PMV's answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use ES6 and the `for... of` loop, Alberto's answer is your best bet, and the cleanest option.

If you're limited to ES5, you can use `for ... in` as well.  As you've found, `for ... in` only enumerates the keys (the property names), not the property values, but it's easy to get the property value once you know the property name:

```
var abilityName, ability;

for(abilityName in window.abilities){
    ability = window.abilities[abilityName];
    if(ability.unlocked){
        $("#abilities").append(genAbilityCard(ability.name,ability.image,ability.description,ability.action));
    }
}
```

The fact you're getting the property names means you ARE successfully enumerating the properties.  Javascript is just a bit weird in how `for ... in` works.

Comment: I don't know what would limit me to ES5; Alberto's code worked, but thank you for going into more detail!

Comment: @SPavel It really depends on your target platform / target browsers.  IE11, for example, doesn't support most features of ES6 including `for... of`.  For more details on what is supported in which environments, you can check https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ .